# ¿Como eliminar lados de un cuadrado en canvas?

Tags: javascript, algoritmos, canvas

estoy haciendo un algoritmo para la generación aleatoria de un laberinto, la estructura de este la estoy tratando de hacer con Canvas empezando por una cuadricula como esta:
[image: Cuadricula hecha con canvas]

y asi es el codigo de esta:

```js
(function createCeldas (celdaSize, rows, columns) {

    for(let c = 0; c < columns; c++) {
        let row = [];
        for(let r = 0; r < rows; r++) {row.push(new Celda(r, c, celdaSize, ctx))}

        celdas.push(row);
    }

})(canva.width/10, 10, 10);
```

```js
export default class Celda {

    constructor(x, y, celdaSize, ctx) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.celdaSize = celdaSize;
        this.ctx = ctx;

        this.visited = false;
        this.walls = {
            west: true,
            north: true,
            east: true,
            south: true
        }
        this.drawCelda(this.x,this.y, this.celdaSize, this.ctx);
    }

    drawCelda(x, y , celdaSize, ctx) {
        ctx.strokeRect(x*celdaSize, y*celdaSize, celdaSize, celdaSize);
        console.log(celdaSize);
    }

    
}
```

el problema que tengo es que a la hora de generar el laberinto quiero quitar muros/lados de las **celdas**(cuadrados) pero debido a que lo hice con el metodo **strokeRect()** creo que no se puede hacer, ¿como lo podria cambiar o que podria hacer para poder eliminar muros/lados de los cuadrados?

Ejemplo de lo que quisiera poder eliminar:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Con muro me imagino te refieres a una columna completa de toda la izq, o toda la derecha imagino?, o a que te refieres?

Comment: @Riven ya edite un poco la publicacion y puse una imagen, creo que ya me doy a entender mas que es lo que quiero eliminar cuando me refiero a muros